# POSTGRES Function taking long time after executing it few times

Tags: java, postgresql

I am calling an simple upsert function in postgres using java.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS UPSERT
CREATE FUNCTION UPSERT(integer,real,real,real,int,real,int,int,int,int,int,real,int,character varying,character varying,int,character varying, timestamp without time zone,real,int,int,int,int,boolean) RETURNS text AS $$

DECLARE
       reccount integer := 0;
       BEGIN


SELECT COUNT(*) INTO reccount FROM mytbl  WHERE id =  $1;    

IF reccount = 0 THEN 

    EXECUTE  ' INSERT INTO mytbl  
 VALUES ( $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($3, $2), 4326), $18 )'
 USING  $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22 , $23;              

ELSE 

 EXECUTE  'UPDATE mytbl  SET ..... WHERE id =  $1' USING $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19,
$20, $21, $22 , $23;    

END IF ;

RETURN 'V' || reccount ;    

END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am trying to write 2500 records.After writing 250+ records, it is slowing down the process a lot .After writing a few records, same operation is taking a long time.It was initially taking few milliseconds after writing 250+ records it slowly increase to 30 or 40 sec. However if I remove index and just inserts or updates with out doing a select first everything is working fine.It is select statement that is slowing down after a while.I am calling the above function again and again using a java for loop.

What could be happening ?

Below is the java code.

```
 CallableStatement upperProc = _conn.prepareCall("{ call UPSERT( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? ) }");
           //upperProc.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);

           upperProc.setInt(1, message.getsi());
           upperProc.setFloat(2, ..);
           ....
                   ....
           ....
                   upperProc.setInt(23, ...);
           upperProc.setBoolean(24,inCache );
```

Comment: Not sure if that's the cause, but `count(*)` is going to take longer the more records there are in the table. Why don't you change that code to `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytbl where id = $1) THEN` update `ELSE` insert?

Comment: @Realskeptic. I tried your suggestion and it did not work ,but it is processing a lot more records before slowing down

Comment: OK, and are you using it in Java in batch mode? Show the Java code as well.

Comment: First, let's check if the problem is in postgres' side or in java's side. Try to run the script that inserts 2000+ records in pgAdmin and see if it is taking too long. If not, the problem is in java's side, otherwise the problem is in postgres, and then we can "attack" the right one.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Your solution worked .I think function did not get refreshed when I tested first time.It is working fine by changing  count(*)  to IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytbl where id = $1) .Please put it as an answer I will mark it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COUNT` expects to use more than one row, and is very likely to take more time the more records there are in the table.

It's preferred to use an `EXISTS` query, which is always going to be looking for just a single row that matches the condition.

So we can dispose of the `reccount` variable, and write a condition like:

```sql
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytbl WHERE id = $1 ) THEN

    EXECUTE 'UPDATE mytbl ...';

ELSE

    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO mytbl ...';

END IF;
```

**Notes**

- If the insert and update statements are not built dynamically (they always have the same structure, just the values differ), it would be more efficient to use just `INSERT INTO` and `UPDATE` directly instead of `EXECUTE` which is used for dynamically-built queries.
- Another option is to attempt to update the record, and if no record was updated, to do the insert. In this case, keep the variable `reccount`:

  ```sql
  EXECUTE 'UPDATE mytbl ...';

  GET DIAGNOSTICS reccount = ROW_COUNT;

  IF reccount = 0 THEN

       EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO mytbl ...';

  END IF;
  ```

  If you take my first advice about not using `EXECUTE`, then you can use the `FOUND` variable instead:

  ```sql
  UPDATE mytbl SET field1 = $1, field2 = $2, ....;

  IF NOT FOUND THEN

       INSERT INTO mytbl (field1, field2, ....) VALUES ($1, $2, ...);

  END IF;
  ```

  `GET DIAGNOSTICS` and `FOUND` are documented in [section 40.5.5 of the PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS).